# No module named 'torch.autograd'

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

Working with torch package:

```
import torch

from torch.autograd import Variable

x_data = [1.0,2.0,3.0]

y_data = [2.0,4.0,6.0]

w = Variable(torch.Tensor([1.0]), requires_grad = True)

def forward(x):

return x*w

def loss(x,y):

y_pred = forward(x)

return (y_pred-y)*(y_pred-y)

print("my prediction before training",4,forward(4))

for epoch in range(10):

for x_val, y_val in zip(x_data,y_data):

l= loss(x_val, y_val)

l.backward()

print("\tgrad: ", x_val, y_val, w.grad.data[0])

w.data=w.data-0.01*w.grad.data

w.grad.data.zero_()

print("progress:", epoch, l.data[0] )

print("my new prediction after training ", forward(4))
```

Got error:

```
runfile('C:/gdrive/python/temp2.py', wdir='C:/gdrive/python')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\gdrive\python\temp2.py", line 11, in <module>

from torch.autograd import Variable

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.autograd'
```

Command `conda list pytorch` brings:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\g\.conda\envs\test:

#

# Name Version Build Channel

(test) PS C:\gdrive\python>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Your `conda list` isn't showing that pytorch is installed. Install it with `conda install -c pytorch pytorch`

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the `Variable` type was deprecated long ago (before pytorch 1.0) and is no longer actually doing anything other than setting the requires_grad member of the tensor. What you have is equivalent to `w = torch.Tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)`

Comment: _Command `conda list pytorch` brings:_ Nothing...? Can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have installed pytorch using conda.
Might be you have **torch** named folder in your current directory. 
Try changing the directory, or try installing pytorch using pip.
This https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1851 might help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

People who are using pip:

```
pip install torchvision
```